# If $L(f,P)=L(f,Q)=U(f,Q)=U(f,P)$, then $L(f)=U(f)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $P$ be $\left \{ 0,1/2,3/4,7/8,15/16,...,1 \right \}$ a partition of closed interval $[0,1]$.

Let's say $P\subseteq Q$. ($Q$ is a refinement of $P$.)

Then we have $L(f,P)\leq L(f,Q)\leq U(f,Q)\leq U(f,P)$

But, if $f$ is defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if }
 1-2^{-2k}\leq x\leq 1-2^{-(2k+1)} \text{ for } k=0,1,2,...\\  0 &
 \text{ if } 1-2^{-(-2k+1)}<x<1-2^{-(2k+2)} \text{ for } k=0,1,2,...\\ 
0 & \text{ if } x= 1 \end{cases}$$ with any $Q$, we will always have $L(f,P)=L(f,Q)=U(f,Q)=U(f,P)$.

In this case, can we conclude that $L(f)=U(f)$ so that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$?

So, in general, can we say that "If $L(f,P)=L(f,Q)=U(f,Q)=U(f,P)$, then $L(f)=U(f)$"?

Comment: Usually partitions in Riemann sums only have a finite number of points, but I guess this dosen't change the definition of the integral since you can approximate countable partitions with finite ones.

Comment: Regarding the last statement I would say this is correct: If there exist partition $P$ such that for any refinement $Q$ of $P$ we have $L(f,Q)=U(f,Q)$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and the integral is this common value. This is because you can intersect an abitrary partition $Q$ with $P$ to obtain a refinement, so you lose nothing by considering only refinements of $P$.